# Нужно восстановить из дампа только настройки таблиц

Tags: postgresql

Побились настройки таблиц, или кто-то их удалил. Отсутствуют индексы, некоторые указания что колонка является первичным ключом и т.д.

Есть ли возможность восстановить из дампа только настройки не касаясь содержимого таблиц?
Если нельзя, то как вести себя в таком случае?

Comment: *как вести себя в таком случае?* Восстановить из дампа всё во временную БД и взять-перенести только нужные настройки.

Comment: @Akina, как же это сделать?